# Unable to import all values from google sheets to sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to import data from google sheets to mysql. I saved the google sheet as .csv. One of the columns square_feet has very few entries so there are a lot of blank cells. I am unable to import any row which has those blank cells. The error I'm getting is.

```
INSERT INTO `airbnb` VALUES ('2265', 'Austin', 'TX', '78702', 'Austin', 'United States', 'House', 'Entire home/apt', '4', '', '$225.00', '$100.00')
```

#1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'square_feet' at row 1

The column square_feet when created was given data type int not null, no default value assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are specifying '' as the value, no default value would be used even if there was one specified.

You are getting the error because 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES' mode is enabled, which in essence tries to ensure that the values you think you are setting are what you actually are going to get.

If you disable it for the session, with:

```
set @@sql_mode=replace(@@sql_mode,'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','');
```

your insert will succeed, and set square_feet to 0.

If you need to affect a different session, you can set it globally with:

```
set global sql_mode=replace(@@sql_mode,'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','');
```

(which will last until the database server is restarted) or change it in the mysql config file.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. Gave the same error. I'm using the import function in phpmyadmin.

Comment: I'm guessing that starts a new session.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you! Only error I got now was #1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'. I checked the sheet I'm importing from and it has no 0 value in the id column which is the primary key. Any idea why I got the error?

Comment: Sorry, found the problem. There was a cell which had a 0.03 value at the bottom of the spreadsheet. Thank you once again.